# How to cancel file upload and show progress with %?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I want to cancel upload and show progress with %. How can I do?  Please let me know if you have any suggestion. Here is my code :

```
var uploaderTable = $("#fileUploadTable");
                if (uploaderTable[0]) {
                    _uploader = new AjaxUpload(uploaderTable , {
                        action: "fileupload.ashx",
                        name: "doc",
                        onSubmit: function (file, extension) {
                            /// code
                        },
                        onComplete: function (file, response) {
                            /// code
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use XMLHttpRequest object. To get upload progress use "progress" event, and to cancel the event "abort" method.

```
// get upload file element
var uploadFile = document.getElementById("uploadfile");

// Create a FormData instance
var formData = new FormData();
// Add the file 
formData.append("upload", uploadFile.files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// to calc progress
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
    var progressPercent = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
    // do whatever you want to do with percent
}, false);

// know when file is sent (or failed)
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        progress.className = (xhr.status == 200 ? "success" : "failure");
    }
};

// start upload
xhr.open("POST", uploadUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.send(formData);


// to cancel sending: xhr.abort();
```